# C++ - Graph implementation for data types other than int

Tags: c++, graph, generics

I am learning graphs and most of the implementations that I see are meant for `int`. So, I decided to code an example that can take other data types such as `char` or `float`. I did see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91965/generic-graph-abstract-data-type-implementation-in-c) prior to posting my example (but not prior to coding my example). The example in the link is similar to creating a `Tree` where a separate `Node` class is used to keep track of node value, left and right child. In the link, instead of left and right child, the `GraphNode` class keeps track of neighbors.

My code does not use that approach and instead keeps the Adjacency List completely to `Graph` class, similar to usual implementations meant for `int` type. The idea is that if anyone needs to define a custom data type, it can be coded later (So, my code does not have a counterpart for `GraphNode` yet). The Graph is initialized by a `vector` of edges. The edges are represented by `std::pair` of nodes/ vertices involved. I have posted my code below. I am interested in knowing if there is a way to represent adjacency list, better than a map of lists, using `stl` containers, and can still handle different data types. However, any reviews or improvements or suggestions are welcome:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

template<typename T>
void print_list(std::list<T> l)
{
    typename std::list<T>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = l.cbegin(); it != l.cend(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
class Graph
{
    //Undirected Graph
    std::map<T, std::list<T>> adj_list;
public:
    Graph(std::vector<std::pair<T, T>>);
    void add_edge(std::pair<T, T>);
    size_t size();
    void print_adj_list();
};

template<typename T>
Graph<T>::Graph(std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> edges)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
    {
        this -> add_edge(edges[i]);
    }
}

//Undirected Graph
template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::add_edge(std::pair<T, T> edge)
{
        adj_list[edge.first].push_back(edge.second);
        adj_list[edge.second].push_back(edge.first);
}

template<typename T>
size_t Graph<T>::size()
{
    std::cout << "Size of Graph(no. of vertices): " << std::endl;
    return adj_list.size();
}

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::print_adj_list()
{
    std::cout << "The Adjacency List: " << std::endl;
    typename std::map<T, std::list<T>>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = adj_list.cbegin(); it != adj_list.cend(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it -> first << "\t";
        print_list<T>(it -> second);
    }

}
int main()
{
    /*std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
    v.push_back({1, 2});
    v.push_back({2, 8});
    v.push_back({2, 5});
    v.push_back({2, 4});
    v.push_back({3, 4});
    v.push_back({5, 9});
    v.push_back({5, 7});
    v.push_back({5, 6});
    Graph<int> g{v};*/

    std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> v;
    v.push_back({'a', 'b'});
    v.push_back({'b', 'h'});
    v.push_back({'b', 'e'});
    v.push_back({'b', 'd'});
    v.push_back({'c', 'd'});
    v.push_back({'e', 'i'});
    v.push_back({'e', 'g'});
    v.push_back({'e', 'f'});
    Graph<char> g{v};
    g.print_adj_list();
    std::cout << g.size() << std::endl;
    g.add_edge({'i', 'k'});
    g.add_edge({'f', 'k'});
    g.print_adj_list();
    std::cout << g.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pass parameters by `const &`**

In `print_list` and your `Graph` constructor, you pass in the parameters by value.  This will make unnecessary copies of the vectors.  Passing in the values by const reference will avoid making these copies.

**Make use of the `auto` keyword or range-based for loops**

You have several places with a long type name to get the type to use for an iterator.  These would be great spots to make use of the `auto` keyword.  For example, `auto it = l.cbegin()`.

However, in these cases, you can do better.  You can use the range-based for statement instead.

Combining these for the `print_list` function gives us

```
template<typename T>
void print_list(const std::list<T> &l)
{
    for (auto v: l)
        std::cout << v << '\t';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Similar changes can be made to your `Graph` constructor and `print_adj_list`.

You can also pass the pair to `add_edge` by const reference, although with the small types you're using that won't really gain much.

`add_edge` assumes that all your edges are bidirectional.  Some adjacency lists have edges that only go in one direction.

Do you need that `cout` in `size`?  All it is really doing is telling you that the function has been called.

You should be able to call `print_list` without having to specify the type.  The compiler should be able to deduce the template type to use.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will make the changes corresponding to const & and auto. I made an assumption that it was a bidirectional graph. I felt that the output statement in size makes the results more presentable. I was using eclipse and it showed an error when I didn’t specify type for print_list. This was before compiling, when eclipse inspects the code automatically. So, that’s probably an eclipse issue. However, is the overall logic of implementation correct?